# creating a gui fro FPDF to allow users to save the PDF genarated

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, fpdf

Has anybody created a gui that allows the user to select the save spot of your generated fpdf because currently i have it automatically save to a file but i would like to give the user the ability to save wherever they choose

Comment: Have You searched anything on google (or whatever search engine You use)? Anyhow You first of all should provide You code but in this case I can suggest You these two functions `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename()`, `tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile()` first You have to import `import tkinter.filedialog` tho and then look at the arguments

Comment: thank you i will try it out, sorry about not providing the code its just several lines long